# write Recursion as a Binomial Coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, recursion, binomial-distribution

supposedly I have this recursive function : 
$$ f(n,n)= f(n-1,n) + f(n,n-1) + f(n-1,n-1) $$
with 
$$ f(1,1) = 1 $$ 
$$ f(x,0) = 0 $$ 
$$ f(0,x) = 0 $$
The goal is to write this as a sum of binomial coefficients, something like this:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{-}{-}\binom{-}{-} $$
I sat the entire day on it and I still cannot find a way to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sequence https://oeis.org/A001850, the formula being the head line . See the comment by B. Cloitre of 2002.

Comment: thank you for the help :)